# Producing EntityManager in a Hybrid Tenancy Context

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have this requirement in which every client must have his data stored individually in a separated database.

I would like to achieve the following structure:

1. A global microservice handles authentication and also provide information about the database in which the client data is stored.
2. The others microservices, when requested, query the auth service to know the client database information, only then the entity manager gets produced.

I am struggling to properly manage the state of the `EntityManagerFactory` instances.

I've tried to store in in a `WeakHashMap` but some buggy things started to happen. Like a simple `findById` throwing exceptions.

I am actually using JEE with DeltaSpike data running on a Payara server.

Anyone have ever done that using a similar stack?

Comment: A few code could help to re-validate your issue.

Comment: Is the set of databases fixed and known at deployment time (or even at development time)?

Comment: No, its dynamical @NikosParaskevopoulos

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `bean managed transaction`, then it becomes even easier to use `CDI` to manage this kind of entity manager factory resource.

First create a datasource context annotation.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, PARAMETER, FIELD, METHOD})
public @interface Datasource {

    /**
     * This may be the database url or whatever.
     */
    @Nonbinding
    String value() default "";

}

@SuppressWarnings("AnnotationAsSuperInterface")
public class DatasourceLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Datasource> implements Datasource {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7485753390480718735L;

    private final String dbName;

    public DatasourceLiteral(final String dbName) {
        this.dbName = dbName;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return dbName;
    }

}

@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerFactoryProvider {

    @Produces
    @Datasource
    @ApplicationScoped
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        final Annotated annotated = ip.getAnnotated();
        final Datasource datasource = annotated.getAnnotation(Datasource.class);

        /**
         * Add relevant jpa properties
         */
        final Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();

        /**
         * The main point is here.
         */
        jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", datasource.value());

        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit-jpa", jpaProperties);
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes @Datasource final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        emf.close();
    }

}

@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleUserDatasource {

    @Any
    @Inject
    private Instance<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactories;

    public void doSomething(final String user) {
        final UserInfo userInfo = authenticationService.getUser(user);
        final Datasource datasource = new DatasourceLiteral(userInfo.getDatasource());
        final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactories.select(datasource).get();

        /**
         * You could also actually inject this.
         * Do whatever you want with it inside a transaction and close it too.
         */
        final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

Comment: The provided code don't work, `6: Cannot inject injection point metadata in a non @Dependent scoped bean: [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Datasource @ApplicationScoped public fortuna.backend.comum.producers.EntityManagerFactoryProducer.entityManagerFactory(InjectionPoint)`